# google storage transfer api - Failed to obtain the location of the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I got exception while I am using java library `google-api-services-storagetransfer` to call `Google Storage Transfer API`.

> Failed to obtain the location of the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket
>   ________ due to insufficient permissions.  Please verify that the necessary permissions have been granted.

(Full Error Message is at bottom)

But even if I gave my service account `Owner` role. This error still occurs.

While I was debugging without clue, here is what I tried

- using another service account
- assign more role to my service account
- using another gs bucket

Only when I using some gs bucket as `GcsDataSink` It works (without exception `Failed to obtain the location of the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket ________ due to insufficient permissions`)

But bucket I want to use as GcsDataSink does not.

How can I debug this problem further? 
Any advice?

---

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Failed to obtain the location of the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket ________ due to insufficient permissions.  Please verify that the necessary permissions have been granted.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Failed to obtain the location of the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket ______ due to insufficient permissions.  Please verify that the necessary permissions have been granted.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at GoogleStorageTransferFacade$.createJobForTianjinReplica(GoogleStorageTransferFacade.scala:65)
    at GoogleStorageTransferFacade$.main(GoogleStorageTransferFacade.scala:74)
    at GoogleStorageTransferFacade.main(GoogleStorageTransferFacade.scala)
```

Comment: If I create TransferJob in Web Console once, "TransferJob create call" with API call doesn't fail. wired..

Comment: Could you share which code are you using? Sanitising any private information, of course.